# Can template matching in OpenCV deal with two same-sized images?

Tags: opencv, similarity, template-matching

I want to use template matching in OpenCV to get the similarity of two images. As we all know,template matching is usually used to find smaller image parts in a bigger one. Here is my question. I find when template image and source image are same-sized, the result matrix get from function matchTemplate() is always 0, even if the two images are exactly the same one.

Can template matching in OpenCV deal with two same-sized images?

Comment: Could you show your code? I tried the official demo, it worked well when two pictures were the same.

Comment: @pwwpche, my code comes from opencv tutorial[link]http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html. I don't know why i failed.

Comment: @pwwpche,I figured it out. When i commented this following code, "  normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );", it worked well. But, could you explain the reason to me ? Thanks.

Comment: Template matching works fair enough for same-sized images, what is the error you're getting? Sample code/images would be helpful.

Comment: `normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() )` means that the `result` matrix will be masked by `Mat()` (so it will be masked by nothing), and scaled so that minimum value in the matrix is `0` and maximum value in the matrix is `1`. Still, this can't explain your problem, so please paste your image here and I will check what is the result matrix you've got.

Comment: @pwwpche, I can't paste my image because of low repulation.In fact, you can try any image.try the famous baboon.jpg for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I should apologize first: the value of the matrix is indeed zero after normalization, as long as the two pictures are of the same size. I was wrong about that:)

Check out this page:
[OpenCV - Normalize](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=normalize#normalize)

Part of the OpenCV source code:

```
void cv::normalize( InputArray _src, OutputArray _dst, double a, double b,
                    int norm_type, int rtype, InputArray _mask )
{
    Mat src = _src.getMat(), mask = _mask.getMat();

    double scale = 1, shift = 0;
    if( norm_type == CV_MINMAX )
    {
        double smin = 0, smax = 0;  //Records the maximum and minimum value in the _src matrix
        double dmin = MIN( a, b ), dmax = MAX( a, b );
        minMaxLoc( _src, &smin, &smax, 0, 0, mask );  //Find the minimum and maximum value
        scale = (dmax - dmin)*(smax - smin > DBL_EPSILON ? 1./(smax - smin) : 0);
        shift = dmin - smin*scale;
    }

    //...

    if( !mask.data )
        src.convertTo( dst, rtype, scale, shift );
    else
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Since there is only one element in the result array, `smin` = `smax` = `result[0][0]`

```
scale = (dmax - dmin)*(smax - smin > DBL_EPSILON ? 1./(smax - smin) : 0);
      =  (1 - 0 ) * (0) = 0
shift = dmin - smin*scale
      = 0 - result[0][0] * 0
      = 0
```

After that, `void Mat::convertTo(OutputArray m, int rtype, double alpha, double beta)` uses the following formula: (`saturate_cast` has nothing to do with your problem, so we can ignore it for now.)

[image: convertTo]

When you call `normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() )`, whatever the element in the matrix is, it will execute `src.convertTo( dst, rtype, scale, shift );` with `scale` = `0`, `shift` = `0`.
In this `convertTo` function,

```
alpha = 0, beta = 0
result[0][0] = result[0][0] * alpha + beta
             = result[0][0] * 0 + 0
             = 0
```

So, whatever the value in the result matrix is:

As long as the image and the template are of the same size, size of the result matrix will be 1x1, and after normalization, the result matrix will become a `[0]`.